# Convolutional neural network

Tags: conv-neural-network

In reasearch paper " http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~hic/CS7616/Papers/Szegedy-et-al-2014.pdf " it has been mentioned in the Architecture Section that "In the lower layers (the ones close to the input) correlated units would concentrate in local regions. Thus, we would end up with a lot of clusters concentrated in a single region and
they can be covered by a layer of 1 X 1 convolutions in the next layer".Why will lower layers concentrate in local region and how does 1 X 1 convolution help in covering them?Kindly help.Thankyou